# Eliminar o reemplazar archivo después de utilizarlo [C#-WPF]

Tags: c#, wpf

le expongo mi problema, hoy estaba haciendo un programa para descargar vídeos y música en youtube, iba bien hasta el momento de utilizar la miniatura del vídeo, el programa descarga la miniatura en la carpeta **temp** del SO, pongo el código:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                 client.DownloadFile(new Uri(URL), @"C:\Windows\Temp\Miniatura.jpg");
                    
            }
```

luego de esto todo bien, descarga el archivo, luego ese archivo lo pongo en mi imagen:

```
                Utilities.DonwloadImage(video.Thumbnails.HighResUrl);
                BitmapImage bi1 = new BitmapImage();
                bi1.BeginInit();
                bi1.UriSource = new Uri(@"file:/" + "C:/Windows/Temp/Miniatura.jpg");
                bi1.EndInit();
                IMG_Thumbnail.Source = bi1;
```

Esto va bien hasta el momento que el usuario quiere buscar otro vídeo, simplemente no se reemplaza; estresado encuentro que usando esto funcionaría:

```
                IMG_Thumbnail.Source = null;
                File.Delete(@"C:\Windows\Temp\Miniatura.jpg");
```

Para nada, me da un error que es lógico, no puede eliminar un proceso que se está usando actualmente y ese es el problema. ¿Cómo hago para eliminar ese proceso? Yo intenté descargar 2 imágenes iguales, luego de eso primero le dije que IMG_Thumbnail.Source sea igual a Miniatura1, perfecto, ahora el proceso está con miniatura1, luego en la segunda búsqueda le digo que ahora `IMG_Thumbnail.Source = null` para luego decirle que IMG_Thumbnail.Source sea igual a Miniatura2, por lo tanto, ya no está usando la primera imagen, pero no es así, lo sigue usando, quisiera saber como reparar este programa, intenté usando hilos pero la verdad no entiendo bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza las 2 líneas debajo de los comentarios

```
Utilities.DonwloadImage(video.Thumbnails.HighResUrl);
BitmapImage bi1 = new BitmapImage();
bi1.BeginInit();
bi1.UriSource = new Uri(@"file:/" + "C:/Windows/Temp/Miniatura.jpg");
//Adiciona la opción de caché solo durante la carga
   bi1.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
//Adiciona que se ignore las imágenes recargadas anteriormente
   bi1.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
bi1.EndInit();
IMG_Thumbnail.Source = bi1;
```

Comment: ¡Funciono! ¡Muchísimas gracias! Te lo agradezco mucho, enserio.